# Passing variadic template to pthread_create

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I understand that `pthread_create` accepts a `void*(*)(void*)` argument and a `void*`, so I have made 2 (failed) attempts to wrap a Function and Args...:

a. Creating a C-style `void *run(void*)` function that will call an `std::function` object that was passed to it:

```
class thread
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void()> functor_t;

    static void* run(void* f) 
    {
        functor_t* functor = (functor_t*)f;
        (*functor)();
        delete functor;
        return nullptr;
    }

    template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
    explicit thread(size_t stack_size, Callable && callable, Args&&... args) {
        auto task_ptr = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(callable(args...))()>>(
            std::bind(std::forward<Callable>(callable), std::placeholders::_1, std::forward<Args>(args)...)
            );
        functor_t* functor = new functor_t([task_ptr]() {
            (*task_ptr)();
        });

        pthread_attr_t attr = { 0};
        if (pthread_attr_init(&attr) == 0)
        {
            m_joinable = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, stack_size) == 0 &&
                         pthread_create(&m_id, &attr, &run, functor);
            pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
        }
    }
private:
    pthread_t   m_id        = -1    ;
    bool        m_joinable  = false ;
};
```

This causes the following error in GCC 4.8.5:

> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct
>   std::_Bind_simple(std::_Placeholder<1>, int))(int*)> >()>’:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/future:1284:55:   required from ‘void
>   std::__future_base::_Task_state<_Fn, _Alloc, _Res(_Args
>   ...)>::_M_run(_Args ...) [with _Fn = std::_Bind(std::_Placeholder<1>, int))(int*)>; _Alloc = std::allocator;
>   _Res = void; _Args = {}]’ thread.cpp:17:1:   required from here /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1697:61: error: no type named ‘type’
>   in ‘class std::result_of(std::_Placeholder<1>, int))(int*)> >()>’
>          typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
>                                                                ^ /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1727:9: error: no type named ‘type’
>   in ‘class std::result_of(std::_Placeholder<1>, int))(int*)> >()>’
>            _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
>            ^

b. Following this example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6c607514601b013

```
class thread
{
public:
    template< typename Callable, typename... Args >
    explicit thread(size_t stack_size, Callable&& callable, Args&&... args )
    {
        auto l = new auto([=]{ callable(args...); });
        auto te = [](void* rp) -> void*
        {
            auto p = reinterpret_cast<decltype(l)>(rp);
            (*p)();
            delete p;
            return nullptr;
        };
        pthread_attr_t attr = { 0};
        if (pthread_attr_init(&attr) == 0)
        {
            m_joinable = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, stack_size) == 0 &&
                         pthread_create(&m_id, &attr, te, l);
            pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
        }
    }
private:
    pthread_t   m_id        = -1    ;
    bool        m_joinable  = false ;
};
```

This is supposed to work in clang, but fails in GCC 4.8.5 with:

> In file included from thread.cpp:2:0:
>   thread.h: In lambda function:
>   thread.h:82:37: error: parameter
>   packs not expanded with ‘...’:
>        auto l = new auto([=]{ callable(args...); });
>                                        ^ thread.h:82:37: note:
>   ‘args’ thread.h:82:41: error:
>   expansion pattern ‘args’ contains no argument packs
>        auto l = new auto([=]{ callable(args...); });
>                                            ^ thread.h: In instantiation of
>   ‘struct thread::thread(size_t, Callable&&, Args&& ...) [with
>   Callable = void (*)(int*); Args = {int*}; size_t = long unsigned
>   int]::__lambda4’: thread.h:82:48:
>   required from ‘thread::thread(size_t, Callable&&, Args&& ...)
>   [with Callable = void (*)(int*); Args = {int*}; size_t = long unsigned
>   int]’ thread.cpp:14:32:   required from here
>   thread.h:82:37: error: using
>   invalid field ‘thread::thread(size_t, Callable&&, Args&&
>   ...)::__lambda4::__args’
>        auto l = new auto([=]{ callable(args...); });
>                                        ^ thread.h:83: confused by earlier
>   errors, bailing out

Both ran with the follwing main:

```
int g=5;

void run(int *i)
{
    printf("t\n");
}

int main()
{

    gs_thread t(256*1024, &run, &g);
    printf("m\n");
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Look at my first attempt, I did just that. I've created a simple `run()` function with an `std::function*` as an argument, then `run()` casts it and calls it.

Comment: maybe try to pass `this` as parameter for `run` then you can basically call whatever method you like. Wont be the best solution, but simpler than what you currecntly have

Comment: One problem could be that you're using a very old version of GCC with incomplete C++11 support. If at all possible, try with newer versions of GCC.

Comment: I wish I could. Unfortunately I need to find a way to fix this for 4.8.5

Comment: Use std::thread and not pthreads API.

Comment: I find your code overly complicated. It might be me (actually quite likely), but I dont understand what your code is supposed to do. What is `run` good for, when all it does it calling some callable?

Comment: Also please show how you create a thread object in either case.

Comment: @user463035818 Because `pthread_create` is a C function, and as such it knows nothing of C++ classes and objects.

Comment: Regarding [a] case,  why are you passing `std::placeholders::_1` to bind function, when your bound object is invoked with no parameters ? Remove it and your code compiles.

Comment: @rafix07 this should be an answer.

Comment: In your second attempt, the fix is `auto l = new auto([&callable, args...]{ callable(args...); });` Of course you must make sure the `callable` does not vanish before it is used. This applies to both attempts. IMNSHO callable objects should always be passed **by value**. In addition `m_joinable` is not set correctly 'cause `pthread_create` returns 0 on success ;)

Comment: @n.m.  :)  I wrote my comment to point how to avoid compile-time error,
i am not sure if OP's code will not give runtime-error, it is a bit complicated.

Comment: @rafix07 it will get runtime error because it doesn't do a proper join, and also *may* get another error because the callable argument is passed by reference and may dangle (will not be a problem if the callable is a regular function).

Comment: I can't use std:thread because I must set the stack size

Comment: First code fixed by removing `std::placeholders::_1`  no idea how it got in there in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `std::placeholders::_1,` from the first version it compiles with gcc.